# How to include my `log` package instead of built-in `log` package in `golang`?

Tags: go

I have an `log` package in my project `src` folder. But when I include the `log` package from an another package as following, the `go` seams find the `log` in the system folder instead of my package.

```
import ("log")
```

And seams I cannot using relative path to import `log` package, because `go install` give following error:

> local import "./log" in non-local package

So how can I let the `go` using my `log` package?

Comment: what is the path of your log package?

Comment: It is in `src/log/log.go`

Comment: what is the path of main file?

Comment: Use the full path. Never use relative imports in Go.

Comment: main.go in the same folder as src (with the same parent folder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your package inside $GOPATH

So if your package is in

```
$GOPATH/src/github.com/ZijingWu/awesomeapp/src/
```

your log package would be in

```
$GOPATH/src/github.com/ZijingWu/awesomeapp/src/log
```

then it would be possible to use

```
import("github.com/ZijingWu/awesomeapp/src/log")
```

The paths seams a bit strange tho, and maybe you should consider adding the log package as a completely separate repository on github, so it would look something like.

```
import("github.com/ZijingWu/log")
```

Just using github as an example here, could of course be placed wherever, also just guessing at your username there. Doesnt need to be in github either you can just place it localy on your computer in the $GOPATH, but then noone else would be able to build your package.